# Derivative of a matrix multiplied by its transpose

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

I have seen the [previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2627262/derivative-of-a-matrix-multiplied-by-its-conjugate-transpose) and I tried to follow the answer to solve the problem. But I encountered some problem and I can not get the expected answer $2a_{ij}$. I stuck at the final line since I thought when $k=j$ , we get $da_{ij}a_{ji}+a_{ij}(da_{jj})$.

$$(AA^T)ij=∑_{k=1}^{n}a_{ik}a_{jk}$$
\begin{align}
  d((AA^T)ij)&=d(∑_{k=1}^{n}a_{ik}a_{jk}) \\
             &=∑_{k=1}^{n}[(da_{ik})a_{jk}+a_{ik}(da_{jk})] \\ 
\end{align}

Comment: What are you differentiating with respect to? Are the matrix entries functions of different variables $x_l$? Or (as I guess) are you taking the derivative with respect to the coefficients $a_{ij}$ regarded as independent variables?

Comment: I want to differentiate $AA^T$ w.r.t A. Just like you said, I want to take the derivative with respect to the coefficients $a_{ij}$

Comment: In that case $$\frac{\partial (AA^t)_{km}}{\partial a_{ij}} = \frac{\partial}{\partial a_{ij}}\sum_l a_{kl}a_{ml} = \sum_l \frac{\partial a_{kl}}{\partial a_{ij}}a_{ml} + a_{kl} \frac{\partial a_{ml}}{\partial a_{ij}}$$. But because the coefficients $a_{ij}$ are independent, $\frac{\partial a_{kl}}{\partial a_{ij}}=\delta _{ik }\delta_{lj}$. Therefore the last term above reads as $a_{mj}\delta_{ik }+a_{kj}\delta_{im}$.